# How do I install a working Discourse, docker image in Openshift Origin (3)

Tags: openshift-origin, discourse

I just wanted to know how to install a working **Discourse** **docker** image on **OpenShift Origin**.

I'm not interested in Openshift one or two, just **Origin**.

I just tried the SamSaffrom Discourse image, to no avail: https://hub.docker.com/r/samsaffron/discourse/

This is the error I received:

Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "discourse" with RunContainerError: "runContainer: API error (500): No command specified\n"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It' seems to be an issue with your image. Even when I just try to run your image with docker (without openshift) it complains: No command specified. Probably no CMD in the dockerfile?

Comment: Did anyone get this to work?